# CSS utility library overrides my button style?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a button by writing my own css but also using Tailwind for other styles.

My code for the button is as follows but some of the elements are crossed out.

```
button {
    margin-left: 10px; /*crossed out*/
    padding: 5px 25px; /*crossed out*/
    background-color:  rgba(2,68,62,1); /*crossed out*/
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer; /*crossed out*/
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Is it because Tailwind already has default values for `button`? I know using `!important` is bad practice so how do I fix this? My html for the cta button is:

```
<a class="cta" href="#"><button>CONTACT</button></a>
```

If I reference `.cta` in my css, I can't change the actual CONTACT text; I wanted to use `text-decoration: none`.

I did set a `*` at the top of my css.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #b3b3b4;
}
```

Comment: make sure you `<link>` your custom css file *after* the tailwind styles

Comment: So ```style sheets``` are in ascending order they are linked?

Comment: In a raw sense, yes the DOM & its styles are applied in the ascending order. But there's more to this such as ***specificity***. I recommend you read the guide on mdn- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: If tailwind styles has more specific defintion than your styles behind the specific definition, for example this style in tailwind button.blue { color: blue} and you wrote it button{ color: black} than browser give to prioritymore specific definiton, my advice is use developer tools and find to tailwind class and use same specification classname